# Saving an Excel Worksheet as xml adds quotation marks around some lines

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I have a worksheet that contains a xml script, that is around 15 columns by 70000 rows. I am trying to save this data to a `.xml` file. The current code i am using is:

```
Sub saveXML()
    Dim GenerateSheet As Worksheet
    Set GenerateSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TestCase-")
    GenerateSheet.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & "TestCase-" + Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xml", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows
End Sub
```

This saves it as a .xml file but it seems to add quotation marks around random lines in the file which breaks the xml file.

```
"<con:testCase xmlns:con=""http://eviware.com/soapui/config"" failOnError=""true"" failTestCaseOnErrors=""false"" keepSession=""false"" maxResults=""0"" name=""name"" searchProperties=""true"">"                                                                              
<con:settings/>                                                                             
"<con:testStep type=""request""  name=""TestStep_0001"">"                                                                               
<con:settings/>                                                                             
"<con:config xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:type=""con:RequestStep"">"                                                                             
<con:interface>QuoteService</con:interface>                                                                             
<con:operation>NewRate</con:operation>                                                                              
"<con:request name=""NewRate - Request 1"" outgoingWss="""" incomingWss="""" timeout="""" sslKeystore="""" useWsAddressing=""true"" useWsReliableMessaging=""false"" wssPasswordType="""">"                                                                             
<con:settings>
```

In the worksheet there are no quotation marks around any of the lines.

How can I control, or prevent, this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

The tags that get quoted are invalid. (They miss an end tag and are not self-closing). Add a / before the end of every quoted tag to make them self-closing.

Exemple (notice the "/" near the end)

```
<con:request name="NewRate - Request 1" outgoingWss="" incomingWss="" timeout="" sslKeystore="" useWsAddressing="true" useWsReliableMessaging="false" wssPasswordType=""/>
```

Comment: Can I just save the data as it is. If I copy and paste the data manually, I am able to use the file perfectly. I'm trying to save the data as if I've copied and pasted the information manually to a .xml file.

Comment: @Ross So it would be excel that mess up the xml?

Comment: The worksheet that holds the scripts of about 70000 lines, I can copy and paste that into SublimeText add save it as a xml manually, the script works. It is only when I try and save the the worksheet using vba script above that it adds the quotation marks. But I'm trying to get it so it saves with a button click so I don't have to do it manually as I have about 8 of these workbooks

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar results in other types of file, where lines that contain escaped quotation marks (") are surrounded by quotes themselves.

I'd say run some form of post processing on the saved file, or create an XML map based no the file:

```
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps.Add("[path to your file]", "[rootname]").Name = "[name of map]"
```

You should then be able to save that file as an XML file, though I have not tested this.